# Access is denied when logging in to localhost

Tags: apache, rabbitmq, localhost

I installed RabbitMQ, but on  localhost/127.0.0.1:61613(this is port for STOMP plugin) i have this :

```
Access denied!
You do not have access rights to this object. The file is not readable, or the server cannot read it.

If you think this is a server error, please report it to the webmaster.

Error 403
localhost
Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.8
```

to be honest, I don't know much about servers and all that , so if you could tell me exactly what I should do and see

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your queue is protected by username and password, so you need to login before you can start using it.
https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html#cta.ic